# Checkout and checkin sharepoint file

Tags: vba, checkin, vcs-checkout

I am getting Runtime error 1004: cancheckout method failed near cancheckout and

Compile error: Method or data member not found in line

```
If Workbooks.CanCheckIn(ChkFile) = True Then
```

How do I resolve the issue?

```
Sub ToCheck()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ChkFile As String
    ChkFile = "http://new1....com/Shared%20Documents/file.xlsm"

    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(ChkFile) = True Then 'getting error here
        Workbooks.CheckOut ChkFile

        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True

        Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ChkFile, , False)
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.Run ("'file.xlsm'!Macro1")

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    Workbooks(ChkFile).Activate

    If Workbooks.CanCheckIn(ChkFile) = True Then 'Getting error here
        Workbooks(ChkFile).CheckIn
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you access the file any other way (e.g. by pasting the url into a web browser)?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to check in the file at the end of the Sub even if you failed to check it out at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `ChkFile = "http://new1....com/Shared%20Documents/file.xlsm"` to `ChkFile = "http://new1....com/Shared Documents/file.xlsm"`, i.e. replacing `%20` for a space since the whole path is already within brackets

Answer (score 0):

The CanCheckIn method belongs to an individual Workbook object. You are trying to use it from the Workbooks collection.

Try using this code:

```
If Workbooks(ChkFile).CanCheckIn = True Then
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot of way to resolve this, finally this method worked for me

```
Dim URL as String
Dim wb as Workbook

URL = "http://your.com/path/to/doc.xlsx"          

If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(URL) = True Then
    Workbooks.CheckOut URL
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(URL, , False)
Else
    MsgBox ("Unable to checkout document")
End If
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly as explained in [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This code is essentially the same as the line that causes error in the OP's Sub.